# nuxt project console conflict

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt project in the console it gives such errors, but when I search for that line of code without succeeding I get no

[image]

Tried to change Nuxt and Vue version without success.

How can I remove these errors?

I do not know the reason for their appearance.